# XAMPP Another web server is already running. with attemps

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, lamp

I install XAMPP with Ubuntu 18.04 and got the

```
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
```

and cannot run the Apache server.

After some research I tried

1. restart  all of the process again with xampp restart
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` and it did say that it's stopped

I have no Virtual Box installed

[edited]
after the suggestion of `netstat -tuplen`
here is what I got

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      121        23365      1031/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          23258      1014/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        20354      561/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          22965      780/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          23259      1014/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          22964      780/cupsd           
udp    41472      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           101        20353      561/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          28781      1301/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41584           0.0.0.0:*                           115        25049      795/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           0          24055      939/cups-browsed    
udp    52602      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           115        25047      795/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::53734                :::*                                115        25050      795/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6   29223      0 :::5353                 :::*                                115        25048      795/avahi-daemon: r
```

Comment: Your port is already bound to another process use netstat -tuplen to see what process is listening on the port

Comment: I've edited the post for what I got after do the netstat command

Comment: Ngix is already running on port 80 that should block XAMPP, change the listening port of either one and they should both start without a problem

Comment: I've stopped nginx services and now I can started the Apache one. Problem solved here. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Kill or stop all nginx process by `service nginx stop` or `ps -ef | grep nginx`.
Then start apache service if not work then change the default listening port of apache from the config file.